# When compiling an android-app in eclipse, an older version of the app shows upp in the avd

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, android-virtual-device

The title pretty much says it all. I was making a simple Hello-world app and after having recompiled it a few times the newest versioned stopped showing upp in the avd. It was stuck with the same version no matter how many times i tried recompiling. After having uninstalled the app in the avd, relauched the avd a couple times, etc it started working normally again and updated for each recompile.

Now i just started a new project, added a few buttons and stuff to it and this problem appears again. No matter what I do, it just shows the state of a newly-created project without any editing. I.e with a textfield saying something like "hello*name*activity"

Edit: After playing around a bit more i.e. uninstalled the app in the avd, wiped userdata in the avd, restarted the avd, restarted eclipse, it still just showed the helloactivity-text instead of my app. Finally i rebooted my computer which "solved" it. Very annoying. I can especially imagine this being frstrating when you're not even sure if it's the new or the old version of the app shwing upp, like when trying to fix a bug.

Any idea as how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this with Eclipse's incremental updates, try a clean build, uninstall the app (I see you already tried this) from the avd and finally file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
What exactly is a "clean build"?

Comment: A build after you clean the project. In Eclipse go to Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects -> Start build immediately -> ok.